# Saturation slider in linux?

Tags: laptop, hp, color-management

I can't find a saturation slider like in windows, where you go to your Intel control panel, and there's like color settings and you can just change it, but in Linux, I can't seem to find anything like this.

Just to clarify, I am on a laptop,and i use it for drawing, also you might tell me that I can find it in the nvidia x settings, but unfortunately nvidia disabled digital vibrance or saturation on laptops, so i have to do it from the nvidia control panel.

Comment: Please let us know which version  and flavor of Ubuntu you use.

Comment: ubuntu 16.10, i have no idea what the flavour is

Answer (score 0):

I've found out, that notebooks with nvidia optimus, that the grafics card is only calculating and not responsible for displaying on the monitor. The displaying task is given to the intel cpu...

That means, if you want to change the saturation, you should find out how to set it up with intel's driver settings and not nvidia's driver.

Comment: Please change this to be a more complete answer, otherwise it should be a comment.